# Extracting dimensions with REGEX

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have a table of warehouse parts, and one column has the description of each part. Within the description are the dimensions of the product, always in the format: HeightxWidthxDepth.

The description can be any number of characters long, so the dimensions aren't always in the same position of the string.

This is a sample of what the table looks like :

```
| Part No  | Description               |
| -------- | ------------------------- |
| ABCDEFGH | Cabinet 245 2070x1014x570 |
| AFFDETGL | Shelves 20104 870x300x330 |
```

In my query, I'd like to select each of the dimensions, such that the table looks like this:

```
| Part No  | Height| Width | Depth |
| -------- | ----- | ----- | ----- |
| ABCDEFGH | 2070  | 1014  | 570   |
| AFFDETGL | 870   | 300   | 330   |
```

I've managed to use REGEX to extract the full dimensions from the column with the following query:

```
SELECT
PART_NO,
REGEXP_SUBSTR(DESCRIPTION, '(\d+(\.\d+|)\s?x\s?\d+(\.\d+|)(\s?x\s?\d*(\.?\d+|))?)')
FROM Products
```

But I'm unsure how to split this into 3 separate columns without using something like `INSTR`.

Can anyone tell me what the best method would be for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use capturing groups around the digit patterns and then extract the individual capturing groups using the 6th argument of `REGEXP_SUBSTR`:

```sql
SELECT PART_NO,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(
         DESCRIPTION,
         '(\d+\.?\d*)\s*x\s*(\d+\.?\d*)\s*x\s*(\d*\.?\d*)',
         1,
         1,
         NULL,
         1
       ) AS height,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(
         DESCRIPTION,
         '(\d+\.?\d*)\s*x\s*(\d+\.?\d*)\s*x\s*(\d*\.?\d*)',
         1,
         1,
         NULL,
         2
       ) AS width,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(
         DESCRIPTION,
         '(\d+\.?\d*)\s*x\s*(\d+\.?\d*)\s*x\s*(\d*\.?\d*)',
         1,
         1,
         NULL,
         3
       ) AS depth
FROM   Products
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE products (Part_No, Description) AS
SELECT 'ABCDEFGH', 'Cabinet 245 2070x1014x570' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'AFFDETGL', 'Shelves 20104 870x300x330' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | PART_NO | HEIGHT | WIDTH | DEPTH |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | ABCDEFGH | 2070 | 1014 | 570 |
> | AFFDETGL | 870 | 300 | 330 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=c6bb9b5434ec9db6d6ead4b99f5839d5)*